# Using Spark to download file distributed and upload to S3

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

In my project, there is an application which sends multiple BlogPost information to Kafka, each blog post contains many media file links. I want to write an application that uses Apache Spark to consume that Kafka stream and download all media file links in a distributed way. Each file link will be downloaded into many partitions and they will be combined and persisted to a single file in S3 storage.

Data send to Kafka will have structure like this:

```
class BlogPost {
   id: Long,
   links: List[String]
}
```

Below is the main implementation I intent to apply for my new Spark app:

```
// Create kafka direct stream
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf)
val sc = ssc.sparkContext
val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, Array[Byte], StringDecoder, DefaultDecoder]
(ssc, kafkaParams, kafkaTopics)

// Process Kafka Stream
stream.foreachRDD { rdd =>  

    rdd.foreachPartition (p : BlogPost => {
        p.links.foreach(url => {
            // For each link post we download into multiple parts
            // and save them into single file in S3 storage
            val size = getContentLength(url)
            // Create partitions
            val partitions = partition( size )
            // Start to download partition and persist them into single file in S3          
            sc.parallelize( partitions, partitions.size )
                .map( partition => (partition, downloadPart( partition )) )
                .saveFile("s3://....")
        })      
    }
}

// Compute and create spark partitions
def partition( size: Long ): ArrayBuffer[Partition] =
{[...]}

// Download file part
def downloadPart( partition: Partition ): Array[Byte] =
{[...]}
```

I don't know if this approach is correct. Can anybody help me on this issue or suggest me better solutions. Does S3 support to create file from multiple parts?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `sparkContext.addFile()`.

As per  Spark document

> Add a file to be downloaded with this Spark job on every node. The
>   path passed can be either a local file, a file in HDFS (or other
>   Hadoop-supported filesystems), or an HTTP, HTTPS or FTP URI. To access
>   the file in Spark jobs, use SparkFiles.get(fileName) to find its
>   download location. A directory can be given if the recursive option is
>   set to true. Currently directories are only supported for
>   Hadoop-supported filesystems.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The reason is I want to stream and store directly file parts to S3 storage, I don't want to to store into intermediate storage like HDFS. I don't know if this approach is good or not.